# jquery resets variable to default

Tags: javascript, jquery

when I open the page it sets the css attribute of every object to a new margin, but when I change that variable with jquery again, it resets to the default (the value when the page loaded)

jquery error line:

```
main.btnC.css({ marginLeft: main.espace, marginRight: main.espace});
```

script from jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bVhgD/

Comment: How about editing the css of those elements?

Comment: shouldn't it be `main.btnC = $(this.settings.btnClass)` ?

Answer (score 0):

when you call to .css() so you meant to change css code of object. But as it was mentioned what is main.btnC is? it is cannot be an object as I understand. Should be like this

```
 $('#id').css({});
```

or  other identificator of your element (object) like:

```
   $(this).css({});
```